# Setting up cron at specific time

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

Even though this is simple, i just want to make sure. How do you run a cron schedule every 15minutes from 12pm to 12am

is it:

```
*/15 12-00 * * * php mycommand.php
or 
*/15 12-24 * * * php mycommand.php
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hour is 0-23 I believe, so the first would be correct, else there'd be 25 hours in a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are actually valid I believe. Though 12-00 looks more accurate as far as I'm concerned.

Check [Here](http://cronchecker.net/check?utf8=%E2%9C%93&statement=*%2F15%2012-24%20*%20*%20*%20php%20mycommand.php&button=)

Comment: based from your link both said are working. haha. but will just follow your advice 12-00.thanks :D